# SFML. Точка входа в процедуру inflatereset2 не найдена в библиотеке dll zlib1.dll

Tags: c++, sfml, mingw, msys2, zlib

Изучаю SFML. Работаю с mingw64, собственно sfml устанавливал через pacman. При работе с окнами, фигурами, текстурами проблем не возникало, все компилировалось и работало, если обобщить, то компиляция производится так:

```
main: main.o
    g++ main.o -o main -lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s -lfreetype -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ main.cpp -c -DSFML_STATIC
```

Проблемы возникли, когда решил реализовать свой собственный textbox. При использовании sf::Font , sf::Text компилируется успешно, при запуске выдает окно ошибки **"Точка входа в процедуру inflatereset2 не найдена в библиотеке dll zlib1.dll"**

Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Если вы работаете из MSYS2, то почему SFML установлен самостоятельно, а не оттуда?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ошибся, взял код из старого мейкфайла, вопрос исправил

Comment: А как запускаете результат, из консоли или мышкой из папки?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat из консоли
попробовал мышкой из папки - окно создается, правда размер не соответствует указанным параметрам, плюс высвечивается окно ошибки с указанным ранее текстом